# Properties declared in constructor function vs prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Now before I get flagged for a duplicate question, please hear me out. I know this question has been asked many times before, such as in [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)
However, I have read all those answers and it doesn't make any sense. The answers in these questions basically say that when you put properties in the prototype, then ALL the instances get that change because it's shared. But you can achieve the EXACT same thing by putting the property in the base class from which all other objects inherit from... What I mean is that if you have this code for example:

```
var Car = function(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.printName = function(){
        console.log("Name is: " + this.name);
    }
};

var toyota = new Car("Toyota");
var mercedes = new Car("Mercedes");
var ferrari = new Car("Ferrari");


toyota.printName();
mercedes.printName();
ferrari.printName();
```

If I were to change the top part to:

```
var Car = function(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.printName = function(){
        console.log("PRINTING NAME");
    }
};
```

Then ALL the instances and every other object that inherited from THOSE objects and so on would be updated. Why would you ever use prototypes when you can just change the base constructor function from which you inherit everything from and everything gets updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that you read on other topics is true, but there is also another slightly difference, that is explained on the Microsoft course for javascript development.

From that book:

> each object gets its own copy of the methods
>   defined by the constructor, despite the fact that
>   they are logically all the same piece of code, and
>   each copy of the method occupies its own space
>   in memory and has a corresponding management
>   overhead

So to sum up, it is not only a matter of you will use it, it is also a matter of performance, so both methods are not EXACTLY the same, when you are creating hundreds or thousands of objects of the same time, it could make the difference.

BTW, I'm an instructor for that course so the source is reliable.

Comment: This is what a lot of people miss. That base function is the **constructor**. You don't want to pack everything in a constructor. That's what the prototype is for.

Comment: Yes I knew about the whole memory and performance issue and I understand that having new properties in the constructor function means that every instance get's their own copy. The only thing I don't understand is when people say that when you change the function on the prototype, ALL the instances change. But if you put it in the constructor function then they ALL change anyways so why use the prototype?

Comment: Exactly, thanks Atticus, both methods will accomplish what you want, and it is important to say that form most websites will not matter, but when you are building complex front-end applications with complex and many many instances of the same objects it could impact your performance. Nowadays most computer haver a really good hardware that can give you a lot of memory but it is always a good thing to take in mind.

Comment: No I understand the performance part, its the whole 'changing the instance properties' thing that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Because it is related, not regarding the performance but the memory handling.When you change the prototype, you are not changing all the instances, you are just changing the common memory space that all the instances share. That is not true for constructors.
Constructors are just functions that create new objects. If you use the same constructor to create two objects, each object gets its own set of properties as defined by the constructor function. While this is useful for data properties, the same mechanism is not quite so useful for methods.

Comment: I hope that can enlighten your doubt

Comment: No I do understand that but that has to do with memory. My point is that you will see no difference in the results if you use one method or the other regardless of the memory efficiency.

Comment: Basically my confusion has to do exactly with what mido has posted in terms of changing a method on the prototype later in the program when you could just put that same change in the base constructor for that specific function. And if you wanted to preserve the functionality of the previous function, then why not just make a new function?

Comment: In that case, in most cases there is no difference, but believe me, there will be cases when prototype will be the solution to all your problems, for what you explain, I guess you come from an object oriented programming paradigm, which in general is more "rigid". But for example you can compare this as the usage of DynamicObjects or ExpandoObject on C#, you might need this dynamic behavior for example when you are creating an object on the fly, based on a web service, I need to continue the answer in another comment...

Comment: Also, prototype is THE base for most of the developers when they are trying to use inheritance on javascript objects, you can easily create new "clases" based on other "clases" prototypes

Comment: you can read more about inheritance and the usage of Object.create(prototypeObject, propertiesObject) here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: Does the prototype of the function also contain all the properties you've already set in the constructor in addition to whatever you add on to the prototype? In other words, is the prototype like an exact copy of a function?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your last sentence, but I guess this will clarify your doubts and you can mark the question as solved:
When you create an object by using a constructor function, the new object delegates functionality to the prototype property of the constructor function. What this means is that the new object has access to all of the properties defined in the constructor function and all of the properties defined by the prototype for the constructor function.